# How to get age from dob from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I  have a table where i  have a field. field name is dob where I am storing date of birth as following format `20-feb-2014`.

I am  writing a query to retrieve the rows in which age is between 18 to 35. How can I do this?

I tried the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE gender='male' AND dob BETWEEN 18 AND 40;
```

How can I convert it into the following format? `20-feb-2014`

How can i get my desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better/easier if you stored it as YYYY-MM-DD (MySQL date type) instead of DD-MMM-YYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# object oriented
$from = new DateTime('1970-02-01');
$to   = new DateTime('today');
echo $from->diff($to)->y;

# procedural
echo date_diff(date_create('1970-02-01'), date_create('today'))->y;
```

[See Demo](https://eval.in/84187)

Answer (score 1):

You have to first format your date string to date object by using `str_to_date` and then you can calculate age as `timestampdiff(year, str_to_date(dob,'%d-%b-%Y'), CURDATE())`

```
SELECT * 
from member 
where timestampdiff(year, str_to_date(dob,'%d-%b-%Y'), CURDATE())
between 18 and 40 and gender='male'
```

[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76f79/2)

Answer (score 0):

Create a query which will subtract the current date from the dob value entered in database.